# Guardar objecto JavaScript en un archivo JSON, grunt task

Tags: javascript, json

Soy bastante nuevo en esta herramienta, así que estoy tratando de utilizar todo lo que pueda en tareas. En este momento estoy usando un [plugin para leer documentos en Google Drive](https://github.com/stpe/grunt-gss-to-json), el problema no es la lectura, es la escritura de los json. Es necesario cambiar la forma en que se guarda el JSON porque no es compatible con la forma en que tengo que leerlo.

Ahora mismo la salida es:
all.json

```
[
  {
    "text": "ACCEPT",
    "es": "Aceptar",
    "en": "Agreed"
  }
]
```

y lo que necesito es

es.json

```
{
 "ACCEPT": "Aceptar"
}
```

en.json

```
{
 "ACCEPT": "Agreed"
}
```

Estoy pensando en leer all.json y crear los otros archivos basados en él... *Ya tengo los objetos creado*s pero **no sé cómo escribir los objetos en archivos es.json y en.json**

### Edición

El `transformRow` que estoy usando es el mismo que se encuentra en el ejemplo.

```
transformRow: function (row, header) {
          var rowdata = {};
          Object.keys(row).forEach(function (col) {
            var key = header[col] ? header[col].toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z]/g, "") : col;
            rowdata[key] = row[col];
          });
          return rowdata;
}
```

El detalle es que revisando el código fuente del plugin, cuando se usa la función tranformRow, él retorna un array, lo cual no me sirve para la lectura que necesito realizar.

[Lineas 61-70](https://github.com/stpe/grunt-gss-to-json/blob/master/tasks/gss_to_json.js#L61-L70) del archivo fuente `gss_to_json.js` del plugin grunt_gss_to_json.

```
if (options.transformRow) {
  rows = Object
         .keys(rows)
         .map(function(row) {
           return options.transformRow(rows[row], header);
         })
         .filter(function(row) {
           return row !== false;
         });
}
```

### Resultado

Gracias a @md ya está lista la función. Realmente estaba confundido y ahora me gusta mucho más gruntjs para crear tareas complicadas.

```
grunt.registerMultiTask('tranformar_por_idioma', 'Crea un archivo por idioma segun el archivo base', function () {
    var options = this.options({
      debug: true
    });

    // cargar el json
    var mapping = grunt.file.readJSON(options.input);

    // ejemplo. cambia aqui la transformacion que necesitas
    var salida = {};

    for (var arrayelement in mapping) {
      var key = null;
      for (var keyobject in mapping[arrayelement]) {
        if (keyobject.toUpperCase() === 'TEXT') {
          key = mapping[arrayelement][keyobject];
        } else {
          if (typeof salida[keyobject.toLowerCase()] === 'undefined') {
            salida[keyobject.toLowerCase()] = {};
          }
          salida[keyobject.toLowerCase()][key] = mapping[arrayelement][keyobject];
        }
      }
    }

    if (options.debug) {
      console.log(salida);
    }
    // guarda el nuevo json
    for (var key in salida) {
      grunt.file.write(options.outpath + "/" + key + ".json", JSON.stringify(salida[key]));
    }
  });
```

Comment: no entiendo bien, ¿intentas extraer esos dos json mas compactos del json completo?

Comment: Edita la pregunta y añade el código que has escrito

Comment: si, y en objetos, no en array como ahora mismo el plugin me los está retornando

Comment: solo quiero saber como guardo objetos javascript en archivos json con tareas gruntjs...

Comment: Si, estoy usando nodejs para poder ejecutar el gruntjs. Necesito crear una tarea en el gruntfile que haga los archivos

Comment: Gun muestranos la parte del `transformRow`

Comment: Pregunta actualizada, estoy usando el mismo transformRow que muestra el ejemplo porque según vi en el plugin, él retorna array cuando se usa esa función, lo cual ya me invalida la respuesta que necesito (objeto de clave valor)

Comment: @GunBlade fijate que edite mi respuesta. Saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero registra una tarea que cargue el `json` de salida y lo transforme en el formato que quieres. Modifica esta tarea para hacer exactamente lo que buscas

```
grunt.registerTask('transformar', function() {
    var options = this.options({ entrada: 'entrada.json', salida: 'salida.json');
    // cargar el json
    var arreglo = grunt.file.readJSON(options.entrada);

    // ejemplo. cambia aqui la transformacion que necesitas
    var salida = { };
    salida[arreglo[0].text] = arreglo[0].es;

    // guarda el nuevo json, podrias guardar mas de uno repitiendo la llamada 
    // con otro nombre de archivo
    grunt.file.write(options.salida, JSON.stringify(salida));
});
```

Luego configura ambas tareas, fíjate de usar el mismo nombre de archivo de entrada para esta tarea y de salida en la otra.

```
grunt.initConfig({
  gss_to_json: {
    dist: {
      options: {
        // aqui lo que ya tienes
      },
      dest: 'salida_gss.json'
    }
  },
  transformar: { 
    options: {
      entrada: 'salida_gss.json',
      salida: 'transformada.json'
    }
  }
});
```

Por ultimo las ejecutas en secuencia

```
grunt.registerTask('default', ['gss_to_json', 'transformar']);
```

No lo he probado pero no deberia necesitar grandes cambios, avísame si tienes algún problema.

Comment: Pero como los guardo en archivos json con gruntjs, es lo que necesito

Comment: Si vas a usar la caracteristica multiTaks del plugin, quiza te convenga usar una multiTask en lugar de una tarea simple.

Comment: No está leyendo las opciones, aunque si es de esta forma, no sabía como escribir los archivos, pero ahora tengo la duda de como escribir las opciones en las tareas custom

Comment: fijate que en la definicion de la tarea puse tranfomar en lugar de transformar. quiza de ahi viene el problema, lo voy a editar.

Comment: Ya quedó, lo agregué como resultado en la pregunta pero también coloco esto como solución. Muchas gracias :D